# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'date' with ItemAdapter

Tags: python, scrapy

I can't find the way to use date of list adapter.get('datemaj')

If i use scrapedate with date() i have this error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'date' with ItemAdapter`

If i use scrapedate without date() i have this error:
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'datetime.datetime'`

```
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        scrapedate = adapter.get('datemaj')

        if scrapedate.date() < datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10):
            print("Go")
            print("date de moins de 10 min alors envoyer")
            return item
        else:
            raise DropItem(f"trop vieux {item}")
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'date'

Answer (score 1):

scrapedate is of type list, so you can't do scrapedate.date(), print it out so you can see it.

Comment: the print(scrapedate) are:  ['2021-01-06 07:59:06']  but i dont know how to remove it of list.

Comment: scrapedate[0] to get the first element